# I don't understand why I get the error "IndexError: string index out of range"

Tags: python

INPUT:

```
AEList =[]
    cc = infile.readline().strip()
    while cc != 'EXIT':
        if cc[0] == '3':
            name = 'A'
            AEList.append(cc)
        cc = infile.readline().strip()
```

OUTPUT:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/alexleblanc/Documents/pa8.py", line 81, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/alexleblanc/Documents/pa8.py", line 47, in main
    if cc[3] == '3' :
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Comment: Probably `cc` is returning an empty string at some point

Comment: Your error does not match your code

Comment: What have you tried? Your variable names need to be more descriptive, and should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style. Odds are we could also replace the awkward use of `readline` with a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

One solution will be to check that your string/array is not empty before checking for specific value:

```
if cc and cc[0] == '3'
```

or

```
if len(cc) > 0 and cc[0] == '3'
```

Remember that if you try to access to value at index that doesn't exist you will have this can of error.